# How to activate new device without access to other devices and SMS?

Tags: ios, two-factor-authentication

I am going to travel to the USA next month and I'm willing to buy a new iPhone. Currently, I have a Mac and an iPad and an Android smartphone. When in the USA, I will have neither my Mac nor my iPad with me, and I won't be able to receive SMS through my Android device.

I have two-factor authentication turn on. I don't see how to turn it off on Apple ID page. Is there any way I set up my new iPhone without carrying, let's say, my iPad with me for the trip?

Answer (score 0):

If the new iPhone is set up with the same Apple ID as your other devices you need to turn off Two Factor Authentication for the Apple ID.

#### If you're using iOS 10.3 or later:

1. Go to Settings > [your name] > Password & Security.
2. Tap Turn Off Two-Factor Authentication.
3. Tap Continue.

#### If you're using iOS 10.2 or earlier:

1. Go to Settings > iCloud.
2. Tap your Apple ID > Password & Security.
3. Tap Turn Off Two-Factor Authentication.
4. Tap Continue.